# creating instance-variables at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, runtime, instance-variables, objective-c-runtime

hey i've got a little confusion here..

I'm using the EyeTunes Framework for a little learning project. It's an iTunes Controller.

The framework gave me an array of playlists currently existing in iTunes.
As some playlists contain thousands of tracks, i plan to create arrays of the track-objects of each playlist in the "applicationDidFinishLaunching" method. (and retain those arrays)
That way when the bindings system should display the tracks list of a playlist, it does not have to load that whole list at the moment. So well so far..

Now, to create those track-arrays for each playlist i wanted to do:
(allPlaylists is an array containing all iTunes Playlists [ ETPlaylist* ];
An ETPlaylist returns an array of Tracks with it's "tracks method")

```
for (ETPlaylist *aPlaylist in allPlaylists){

    arrayContainingTracks = [aPlaylist tracks]

}
```

so

1. How do i set a different name for "arrayContainingTracks" in each enumeration?
   And how to do that in the header file, in which all instance Vars have to be declared?
2. and BTW: Up to which level of relationships does an array load it's contents to memory when allocated?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question (why on earth would you like to change the variable name?).  But the following code will insert every tracks of every playlists in `arrayContainingTracks` (assuming it's an instance of `NSMutableArray`):

```
for (ETPlaylist *aPlaylist in allPlaylists)
{
    [arrayContainingTracks addObjectsFromArray:[aPlaylist tracks]];
}
```

Note that all the tracks will be flattened in the array.  If you want to pre-load every track but also keep the playlist's name, store them in an `NSMutableDictionary` instead:

```
for (ETPlaylist *aPlaylist in allPlaylists)
{
    [playlistsByName setObject:[aPlaylist tracks] forKey:[aPlaylist name]];
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that the `ETPlaylist` class has a `name` method.

Comment: Thank you! What i meant was not changing just the name. I thought of: In the first enum.: arrayContainingFirstPlaylistTracks = [FirstPlaylist tracks] >> In the second enum.: arrayContainingSecondPlaylistTracks = [SecondPlaylist tracks] and so on.. I know this is maybe a little weird ;)

Comment: So in your first code snippet, the array would contain all tracks without any information to which playlist they belong?